# How to strengthen a light/mobile wallet such as MyMonero

Tags: mymonero, light-wallet

MyMonero is the only mobile/web wallet for Monero. However, it is a centralized system where the source code (html/javascript) of the mobile wallet is stored in the server. This means that a perpetrator could embed malicious code or create a social engineering to steal the users seed/keys. In what way this could be circumvented or the users maybe alerted when there is a tampering of code.

Answer (score 1):

The article [Javascript Cryptography Considered Harmful](https://www.nccgroup.trust/us/about-us/newsroom-and-events/blog/2011/august/javascript-cryptography-considered-harmful/) goes through this quite well.

> Secure delivery of Javascript to browsers is a chicken-egg problem.

Newer browsers that support [Subresource Integrity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Subresource_Integrity) allow a website to specify a file hash for an external resource (a stylesheet or some Javascript). This is nice but there is nothing stopping an attacker calculating a hash for their malicious code and inserting that into the integrity attribute.